# R: Using forecast() within a user-defined function

Tags: r

I'm writing a function which forecasts some user-inputted data, by fitting an AR model. Outside the function, the code may look like

```
dat <- c(1,1.1,1,1.2)
print(forecast(ar(dat)))
```

This runs just fine.

If this is now put inside a function, like:

```
func <- function(data_input)
{
    temp <- forecast(ar(data_input))
    print(temp)
}
func(dat)
```

I get this error:

> Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

Please could someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the workaround suggested in [Why can't I pass a dataset to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661500/why-cant-i-pass-a-dataset-to-a-function?rq=1)

This seems to work, so could the issue be

> the definition of environments in the parse tree of S4 methods?

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
# library
library(forecast)

# data
dat <- c(1,1.1,1,1.2)

# function definition
func <- function(x){

  (temp <- forecast(ar(x)))

}

# usage
func(dat)
```

However, I do not know why it does not work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried using this code, but it brought up the same error as before for me.